# pass dot as parameter to C macro

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor

I've read different related answers on StackOverflow but none of them gives me the answer to this question.
I need to do concatenation of entities (not necessarily strings) passed to the macro with a separator between them (in my case dot). Here is my code:

```cpp
    #define STR(x) #x
    #define XSTR(x) STR(x)

    #define CONC_(a, b) a ## b
    #define CONC(a, b) CONC_(a, b)

    #define CONC3(_1, _2, _3, S) CONC2(CONC2(_1, _2, S), _3, S)
    #define CONC2(_1, _2, S) CONC(_1, CONC(S, _2))

    #define JOIN_UNDERSCORE(_1, _2, _3) XSTR(CONC3(_1, _2, _3, _))
    #define JOIN_DOT(_1, _2, _3) XSTR(CONC3(_1, _2, _3, .)) // here I pass dot
```

Here is how you can use it

```cpp
    std::string underscore = JOIN_UNDERSCORE(one, two, three);
    std::string dot = JOIN_DOT(one, two, three); // this one doesn't compile
```

I could use another technique to achieve this. Like:

```cpp
    #define APPEND_DOT(x) "." STR(x)

    #define CONCSTR3(_1, _2, _3) CONCSTR2(_1, _2) APPEND_DOT(_3)
    #define CONCSTR2(_1, _2) STR(_1) APPEND_DOT(_2)
    #define CONCSTR1(_1) STR(_1)

    #define JOIN_STR_DOT(_1, _2, _3) CONCSTR3(_1, _2, _3)

    std::string dot_str = JOIN_STR_DOT(one, two, three);
```

and this would work with dot. But the question is how to make it generic by passing the separator.

Here is a link to play around https://godbolt.org/z/MDxsJS

Comment: `std::string` is not a [tag:c] thing.

Comment: In C, `"a" "b"` is equivalent to `"ab"`, so you can do something like this: https://godbolt.org/z/3msmnf

Comment: thank for your comment but I need this macro to be able to generate also variable names. Like: 
```int JOIN_UNDERSCORE(my, awesome, var) = 1;```
that would produce ```int my_awesome_var = 1;```

Comment: Please note that using macros to generate variable names is an _awful_ idea.

Comment: `a ## b` in a macro is used to create a single token by concatenating two. This can be used e.g. as a variable name. `"a" "b"` is used to concatenate string literals. You seem confused about which of these you actually need.

Answer (score 2):

The result of the ## operator must be a valid pre-processor token. `one_` is valid, `one.` is not. That's why underscore works but dot doesn't.

If the intention is to create a string, you can utilize pre-processor string literal concatenation rathern than the token paste operator:

```
#define STR(x) #x
#define JOIN_UNDERSCORE(_1, _2, _3) STR(_1) "_" STR(_2) "_" STR(_3)
```

which can be written generically as:

```
#define STR(x) #x
#define JOIN_SYMBOL(_1, _2, _3, symbol) STR(_1) STR(symbol) STR(_2) STR(symbol) STR(_3)
...
const char* underscore = JOIN_SYMBOL(one, two, three, _);
const char* dot = JOIN_SYMBOL(one, two, three, .);
```

This can't be used to create variable names, but then dots can't be used to create variable names either.

It is possible to do this by skipping the concatenation entirely, but what good that would do, I have no idea:

```
#define DUMB_THING(_1, _2, _3, thingie) _1 thingie _2 thingie _3

#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
  typedef struct { int idea; } stupid_t;
  typedef struct { stupid_t stupid; } really_t;
  really_t really;
  DUMB_THING(really, stupid, idea, .) = 42; 
  printf("%d", really.stupid.idea);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

[`##`](http://eel.is/c++draft/cpp.concat) allows to concatenate **valid** preprocessing tokens forming a **valid** preprocessing token.

In your case, you could use

```
std::string pi = CONCSTR2(3, 141592);
```

as `3`, `3.` and `3.141592` are all valid preprocessing tokens.  But you can't use

```
std::string dot = JOIN_DOT(one, two, three);
```

as `.two` (which is the first concatenation you are doing) is not a valid preprocessing token.  When your final goal is to form a string, better use the string literal concatenation available by juxtaposition.  When your goal is an identifier, you can use your first method.